Ubuntu 22.04 からUbuntu 24.04 にグレードアップしたらlibtinfo5がインストール出来なくなった
Hamilton-Jaobi理論のプログラムを使っているのですが、Ubuntu 22.04.1で動いたものがUbuntu 24.04.1ではlibtinfo5がなくなったようで困っています。
https://github.com/SFU-MARS/optimized_dp.git
optimized_dp$ sudo apt install libtinfo5：パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています... 完了        
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了        
libtinfo5:i386 はすでに最新バージョン (6.4-2) です。
これらを直すためには 'apt --fix-broken install' を実行する必要があるかもしれません。
以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 libtinfo5:i386 : 依存: libc6:i386 (>= 2.33) しかし、インストールされようとしていません
E: 未解決の依存関係です。'apt --fix-broken install' を実行してみてください 


もしかしたらこれらの記事が参考になるかも？ Ubuntu 24.04@WSL2にCUDAをインストールする（libtinfo5が見つからない問題）, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS で cuda-toolkit をインストールした。, Ubuntu 24.04 LTSでTITAN Vを使えるようにした, WSL2のDockerでUbuntu24.04とCUDA12.4の環境を整備

@cubick さんの回答関連で検索したら、この Issue と ガイド の2つが紹介されました。libtinfo5:i386 isn‘t avaiable on ubuntu 24 #4589, How to Install and Uninstall libtinfo6 Package on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 調べてみてください。

こんな記事 【第59回】Ubuntu 22.04 LTSから24.04 LTSへアップグレードできるようになった。どうする？ を見ると 22.04 で問題無いなら Ubuntu をアップグレードしない方が良いかもしれませんね。対象リポジトリでは今のところ 18,20,22 しかサポートされていないようですし。Quickstart (Ubuntu 18, 20, 22)

USN-5477-1: ncurses vulnerabilities | Ubuntu security noticesの影響で、libtinfo5 は security.ubuntu.com リポジトリに置かれています。libtinfo5 amd64 version, libtinfo5 i386 version

AskUbuntuからの情報を得て、いくつか試した結果：
1324 sudo aptitude update
1325 sudo apt -y install aptitude
1326 wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncurses/libtinfo5_6.3-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
1327 python examples.py
1328 sudo apt install libtinfo.so.5

無事optimized_dpが動きました。ありがとうございました。

質問時とは異なるアカウントのようです。もし意図せず複数のアカウントを作成してしまった場合には、ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。 間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？


該当リポジトリの README を読む限り、動作環境として想定しているのは Ubuntu 22.xx までのようです。

Ubuntu 24.xx 以降、libtinfo パッケージはバージョンが変わって libtinfo6 のようです。(これを入れれば動くのかは分かりません)
https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/libtinfo6



libtinfo6ではダメでした。ありがとうございました。確かにUbuntu 22 までの想定です。Windowsのバージョンアップでは経験がありませんが、Ubuntu のバージョンアップは気を付けないといけないのでしょうか。プログラムの制作者にも質問してみたいと思います。
